# Update zoom state on changing timeAxis Step - VisJS

Tags: javascript, timeline, vis.js

I am using VisJs and i am trying to implemente some menu options for change the current scale and step on the time axis.

When i change the step ont the buttons the axis are not displayed correctly. I think that is some problem with the current zoom. Its is possible to fit the axis automaticaly when the steps are changed?

I already try to use zoomMin and zoomMax, but i need to disable the user zoom.

I have this example - http://jsfiddle.net/jgt1v9vn/38/

JavaScript

```
var groups = new vis.DataSet([{id: 0, content: "A", value: 1}]);

 var items = new vis.DataSet([
{id: 0, group: 1, content: "item 0", start: new Date(2014, 3, 17), end: new Date(2014, 3, 21)}]);

var container = document.getElementById("visualization");
var options = { zoomMin: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, zoomMax: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24};

var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container);
timeline.setOptions(options);
timeline.setGroups(groups);
timeline.setItems(items);

document.getElementById("1minute").onclick = function () {  timeline.setOptions({ timeAxis: {scale: "minute", step: 1 }, }); };
```

HTML

```
<div id="visualization">
<div class="menu">
    <input type="button" id="1minute" value="1 MINUTE"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code. Also, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am sorry. Already fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**zoomOut** solved my issue:

```
timeline.setOptions(options);

this.timeline.zoomOut(1);
```